# How to store security configuration in android app

Tags: java, android

I have developed an app which fetches details from my website and displays the info in form of quiz to the user

but I am not able to establish connection to my website and not able to find where to store the security configuration in app

here is my java code to send url and fetch result in a string

```
package com.example.webapp1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        URLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
                url = new URL(strings[0]);
                urlConnection =(URLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                 int data = reader.read();

                 while (data != -1)
                 {
                     char current = (char) data;
                     result += current;
                     data = reader.read();
                 }

                 return result;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.getStackTrace();
            return "failed";
        }

    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String result =null;
    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    try {
        result = task.execute("https://www.imdb.com/list/ls052283250/").get();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("result content",result);
}
```

}